# Nuking off the xib cache

Tags: caching, localization, xib

Due to an ugly series of code sign problems, I decided to import the new files into a previous version of my app retrieved from the backup. At last all went fine and good but for the main controller xib file that keeps on presenting the original layout, notwithstanding I have inserted the localized new ones. I also tried to removed the localized ones but it does not care at all: in all my system I have no xib of that shape and so I think it keep some weird cache somewhere tab it uses not finding a non localized xib. Following this idea I also tried to remove the localization from the Xib files but they still remain in they language folder.

I tried deleting the derived data many times as well as cleaning the build to no avail. What other directory could I delete to get rid of those xib preprocessed files?

Comment: Sorry can't help but I have a similar problem here. I wanted to remove a localization .xib after deciding it was not necessary, but there was no way to remove only one language via the Xcode GUI. So I removed all languages of that .xib and added back the ones I wanted to keep. For some reason I now get a warning saying that the removed .xib is 'missing'... how does it still know about that file I wonder? And when the device is set to the language that was removed, on iOS <= 4.1 the device tries to find that .xib and the app breaks.

Comment: Well... I discovered that the warning was coming up because I had not yet deleted the file from subversion, which is strange because I never told Xcode to have anything to do with subversion. Anyway I committed the deletion to get rid of the warning, and now the app runs ok!! It's amazing how one company can come up with so many ideas that although they may be well-meaning, turn into such time-consuming catastrophes.